# Solaris package upgrade

Tags: solaris, packaging

I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around how Solaris 11 does packaging. I understand that there is a `yum` type packaging approach, but I would expect there to be a `rpm -i` and `rpm -U` approach that allows a package to be delivered and then installed or upgrade.

For now I have tracked down how to make a package, ie `pkgmk` and `pkgtrans`. Given this I can create a "foo_1.0.pkg" file that can be installed like this:

`pkgadd -d foo_1.0.pkg`

However I can not figure out how to upgrade this package with "foo_2.0.pkg":

```
root@hostname # pkgadd -d foo_2.0.pkg   

The following packages are available:
  1  foo     foo
             (x86) private_build

Select package(s) you wish to process (or 'all' to process
all packages). (default: all) [?,??,q]: all

Processing package instance <foo> from </root/foo_2.0.pkg>

foo(x86) private_build

Current administration requires that a unique instance of the <foo>
package be created.  However, the maximum number of instances of the
package which may be supported at one time on the same system has
already been met.

No changes were made to the system.
```

What am I doing wrong? It would appear that i should use [`pkg update`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28984/gkkpy.html#scrolltoc), but this seems to imply that I need to release my pkg in a repo.

Answer (score 5):

First, you aren't using Solaris 11 packaging (IPS) but the legacy SVR4 packaging.

With the latter, you cannot upgrade a custom package. The only way is then simply to remove the old package and install the newer one, which is what `rpm -U` is doing under the hood anyway.

```
pkgrm foo
pkgadd -d foo_2.0.pkg foo
```

Comment: Yes, you are right I should be using IPS. I wasn't clear but I need to support both Solaris 10 and 11, and I'd like to only have one process for both, therefore I'm stuck with the legacy process. Regarding `rpm -U` doing a "remove then add" I don't think that's true, but instead I think it does an overlay. My app uses a memory DB that writes its state into the app directory, so on upgrade we want to overlay so we keep the state. This obviously gets awkward if you need to `pkgrm` and then `pkgadd`. If there is no "update" concept, then i guess we'll need a manual process to restore the "state".

Comment: You are right, `rpm -U` is first installing the new version then removes obsolete files if any. Anyway, if the state file is not delivered by the package but created later by the application, I believe the state file will be preserved by the `pkgrm` command.

Comment: Ahh... you are right. My postremove script does an "rm -rf" of the install directory. I'll confirm that it leaves the "state" like you said. One question though, is there a common flow for what to do with the left over "state" files (this would include logs, temp files, that DB, etc). Should the postremove script tell the user that there are left over files? Should the script be interactive and ask whether the files should be removed or not? what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I was able to workaround it by passing a config  file into the cmd. This is especially useful in a script when used with the "echo |" as it bypasses the confirmation prompt as well.  The config file overwrites the default install properties which are located in a file here: /var/sadm/install/admin/default.  The key is the instance=overwrite line.  I changed some of the others as well, to avoid any other prompts that may come up.  As an alternate solution you can change the default file directly and not have to reference the additional config file.

with myprog1.0 (or 2.0) already installed run the following command.

```
echo | pkgadd -a /opt/myprog/install.conf -d myprog2.0
```

contents of /opt/myprog/install.conf file:

```
mail=
instance=overwrite
partial=nocheck
runlevel=nocheck
idepend=nocheck
rdepend=nocheck
space=ask
setuid=ask
conflict=nocheck
action=nocheck
networktimeout=60
networkretries=3
authentication=quit
keystore=/var/sadm/security
proxy=
```

Answer (score 1):

$UPDATE

This variable does not exist under most installation environments. If it does exist (with the value yes), it means that a PKG with the same name, version and architecture is already installed on the system or that the installing PKG will overwrite an installed PKG. The original BASEDIR is then used.
So, this variable you can use in preinstall or postinstall script for any updation.